# Using DateTime in a For loop, incrementing date Isn't working

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, for-loop

I have this loop, its purpose is to loop through a range of dates and perform some logic to automate adding entries into the database. The issue is that the incrementing portion, date.AddDays(1.0) isn't working, and is always the same result, causing an infinite loop. Any insight?

```
for (DateTime date = DateTime.Now; futureDate.CompareTo(date) > 0; date.AddDays(1.0))
{
    // logic here
}
```

Answer (score 74, accepted):

`DateTime.AddDays` returns a new instance without modifying `date`. At the moment you're throwing away this new instance. Instead, you need to do:

```
for (DateTime date = DateTime.Now; futureDate.CompareTo(date) > 0; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
{
    // logic here
}
```

Also, I'm not sure why you're calling `CompareTo` when you could use the `<` operator. I can't tell whether `CompareTo(date) > 0` is correct without thinking about it for a moment, whereas the intent of the `<` operator is obvious:

```
for (DateTime date = DateTime.Now; date < futureDate; date = date.AddDays(1.0))
{
    // logic here
}
```

Answer (score 8):

DateTime is immutable.  Change to:  date = date.AddDays(1.0)